# How to make gmapping dynamic, or advise any other methods to create mapping of a dynamic environment

Tags: slam, mapping, ros2

it is a general question.

Gmapping seems to be used only for creating a map of the static environment. Once created, it doesn't account for any changes - you add a new object, but it's being ignored and not reflected in the map.

Is there any way to modify gmapping so it can be used for changing environments? What other methods can be used in this case?

I don't care about localization, only need mapping of the dynamically changing environment.

Any thoughts or comments are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept that you're looking for is lifelong mapping. It's an active area of research and there are experimental versions in newer SLAM implementations such as [slam_toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox#lifelong-mapping).

gmapping's implementation will need a significant update to consider supporting these more recent developments as it was not designed with this feature in mind.

Comment: Thank you! So, you're saying that slam_toolbox is dynamically updating the mapping as new obstacles come and go?

Comment: I linked to the paragraph in the documentation which talks about the capabilities that it has. With qualifications and other examples You should read it to understand if it's the same as what you are looking for. And likely do some more research on the term.